# Копирование содержимого Array list?

Tags: java, android

Имеется список "artist". Когда я получаю "artist = parseJson.ParseArtist(result);", то он сохраняет ссылку на список, и соответственно мой "boxadapter" теряет его.

```
ArrayList<Artist> artist = new ArrayList<Artist>();//определение списка
boxAdapter = new BoxAdapter(ArtistActivity.this, artist);// свой адаптер
lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);// инициализация listview
lvMain.setAdapter(boxAdapter);//Установка адаптера

ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson();// класс для парсера Json
artist = parseJson.ParseArtist(result);// возвращает результат
frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();// обновление адаптера
```

Как сохранить в arraylist только содержимое полученного результата?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

создайте в вашем `BoxAdapter` метод типа `setValues(ArrayList<Artist> artists);`
который будет устанавливать новые значения в адаптер, и делайте как-то так:

```
ParseJson parseJson = new ParseJson();// класс для парсера Json
artist = parseJson.ParseArtist(result);// возвращает результат
boxAdapter.setValues(artists);
frameLayout.setVisibility(View.GONE);
boxAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```